# Cross domain application integration?

Tags: javascript, integration, cross-domain

My company has a Java webapp that contains a product catalog feature. We are looking for a way to integrate the catalog into other sites in a way that no server side code would need to be written(on the external sites). I'm just looking for suggestions for ways that one might go about doing something like this... ?

Comment: Is the entire catalog built via JavaScript (i.e., no straight/static HTML)? If so, use Larry K's solution. If it requires static HTML as well as JavaScript, you may have to use an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you assuming that the other sites will include your Javascript software into their html pages?

If so, you can provide the other sites with a javascript include statement that will pull the javascript from your server. Your JS library will then pull the data from your server using JSONP.

It will all work cross-domain. User Interface options to your JS library can be set using JS variables that your library will look for.

Comment: This is more or less what I was thinking... I guess I just needed to hear it from someone else! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also have a serious look into [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)

A way to allow xmlhttp to access your site without problems in IE8 and FF 3.5+

Comment: IE8 and FF sounds like cross browser to me ;) It is not for ALL browsers yet nor for old browsers, but for example at my office we are now finally up to date on both IE and FF. And if you are modifying code on the server, it is so incredibly simple to add this one header